# ImageMagik - Saving as a file is ok, but outputing to web page is corrupted

Tags: php, imagemagick

I am using ImageMagik on my Debian server (apt-get install php5.6-imagick).

As expected, this bit of code reads in a picture and saves a copy elsewhere:

```
$canvas = new Imagick( "/var/www/websites/DisplayScreen/Slideshow Photos/20161016_151555.jpg" );
$canvas->writeImage("/var/www/websites/DisplayScreen/20161016_151555.jpg");
```

When I change the code to:

```
$canvas = new Imagick( "/var/www/websites/DisplayScreen/Slideshow Photos/20161016_151555.jpg" );
header( "Content-Type: image/jpg" );
echo $canvas;
```

and call it from a web page, a file that is a similar size to the original is delevered but is not recognised by the browser (or Paint Shop Pro). The output image seems to have been corrupted.

I have tried **header( "Content-Type: image/jpeg" );** and **echo $canvas->getImageBlob();** as varients to the above, but get the same result.

All help gratefully received...

Comment: Your problem could be the space here "Slideshow Photos" I never have space in file paths as it can cause problems. I would recommend putting the image into the same folder as the code and see if that works.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I don't think the space is the problem as it doesn't prevent the first bit of code working.  Also, if I deliberately misname the file I get an error.  This all suggests that it is finding and reading the file in correctly, it is just when output to the calling web page that a problem occurs.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the problem was that I had a blank line in my php source file before the <?php

This, obviously, was being output ahead of the image and therefore corrupting it (but, also obviously, didn't affect writing the image out to disk).